# perl GD draw a shape

Tags: perl, drawing, gdlib

I am using GD library to draw an image.

Image I am drawing is this http://i39.tinypic.com/apd1f7.png

I am able to manage most of the image however, I do not know how to draw the red portion of the image. The red portion has a sideways triangle on both sides...how can I manage that using the GD lib?

Answer (score 1):

You want filledPolygon, see https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/GD/GD.pm.

Comment: will that be rectangle and then polygon for the arcs or the whole red portion should be a polygon?

Comment: For the red portion you should use one or more polygons.

For the arcs, use filledArc which is also described at the above link.